# One takes an exam, but what about a job interview?

Tags: single-word-requests

As far as exams go, you *take* one, and then you *pass* it or *fail* it.

How about job interviews? If you succeed, you can say you passed the interview. But what if you don't know the result? What's the right verb for participating in a job interview as the interviewee?

> Yesterday I ??? my first interview at Bloomberg but I don't know if I have passed yet and therefore if there is going to be a second one.

NGrams shows there is this valid phrase - *to take an interview*, but it seems to mean *to interview someone*.

Comment: If one is a job applicant, one seeks an interview, receives a request for an interview, schedules an interview, has an interview, and is interviewed.

Comment: Depending on your experience of the particular one, you could for example suffer, endure, complete, enjoy, pass, or indeed ace an interview.  Similarly, you could bluff, breeze, sit or walk one.

Comment: I don't want to reinforce what many might view as an improper use of the word by leaving this as an answer, but nevertheless it is common in my region to hear the phrase "interviewed at <company>" to mean "had an interview at <company>".  I'm reminded of how many people will say "graduated <school>" instead of "graduated from <school>", the former of which is also widely considered to be an improper construction despite its popularity (and, some places, near-ubiquity).

Comment: Note that many people will tell you that they "sit" exams.

Comment: "Have" an interview is definitely the most common usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People either ***have***, ***had***, or *are* ***having*** an interview.

> Yesterday I *had* my first interview at Bloomberg but I don't know if I have passed yet and therefore if there is going to be a second one.

---

You can also simply use ***interviewed***.

> Yesterday I *interviewed* at Bloomberg but I don't know if I have passed yet and therefore if there is going to be a second one.

Answer (score 29):

***[Interview](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/interview)*** (countable, uncountable) a formal meeting at which someone is asked questions in order to find out whether they are suitable for a job, course of study etc

Usages:

***[Have an interview](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/interview):***

> - She has an interview next week for a teaching job in Paris.

***go for an interview (also attend an interview formal)***:

> - I went for an interview at a software company yesterday.

***get an interview:***

> He was one of only five people to get an interview out of more than 100 people who applied.

***be called/invited for (an) interview:***

> a Applicants who are called for interview may be asked to have a medical exam.

***do an interview (also conduct an interview formal):***

> - The interview was conducted in French.

***give somebody an interview (=interview someone):***

> - We gave her an interview, but decided not to offer her the job.

From Longman Dictionary

Comment: Slight variation on *went for* that I hear a lot is *went to*.

Comment: 'had' an interview .. (not only do but have) isn't included in your options but I believe is one of the most common ways of putting it. Also.. restructuring the sentence to use "interview" as a verb might be even better.  "Yesterday I interviewed with Bloomberg" ... the term "interview" is idiomatic enough with use in the context of a job screening that there wouldn't be any misconception that they brought you in to do what a talk show host might do.

Comment: IMO, it's so common that I **had** to make my own answer. Even though this answer might be more beneficial for posterity, it misses the one word that fits the OP's context.

Comment: @Mazura - more than one expression could fit in OP context. I think the answer provides all necessary information to make the choice they think best.

Answer (score 20):

***Attend*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attend)

I attend interviews. I pass (or fail) them. I get (or don't get) the job.

> (verb) 1. Be present at (an event, meeting, or function)
>   ‘the whole sales force attended the conference’

Comment: *Attend* here has the connotation of "sit in on" or "observe". It's definitely not the word to use for the candidate.

Comment: @chrylis What word do you have in mind?

Comment: Attend is the word I use, and it seems to be growing in popularity: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attend+an+interview&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattend%20an%20interview%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure. I *think* that I personally say "have", or possibly "sit for".

Comment: @RoaringFish That's not germane. I'm not saying that the phrase "attend an interview" is not correct English, I'm saying it means something else.

Comment: @chrylis I've only heard people 'attend' interviews, not 'sit in on' or 'observe'. Maybe it's just me and my region.

Comment: @chrylis - when I receive an invitation to attend an interview, I can assure you they do not intend me to just sit and look at them!

Comment: @NVZ - to be fair, I have been invited to sit in on interviews, but in those cases I am there as the interviewer, not the interviewee.

Comment: I've never heard the word "attend" used this way.

Comment: @tparker what have you heard instead?

Comment: "Have" an interview, as I commented to the OP.

Comment: @tparker I see. If I _have_ an interview tmrw, then I will _attend_ it. They serve two different purposes

Answer (score -1):

what about undertake "commit oneself to and begin ..."?

I undertook an interview

that would leave the question open, if you passed it or not..